# out_of_range exception with strings

Tags: c++, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I was trying to understand `out_of_range` exception in strings

```
#include<iostream>
#include<exception>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try{
        string str = "Hello";
        str.at(100);//throws exception and get caught
        //str[100]; //this is a run time error, program crashes
    }
    catch (out_of_range &e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

}
```

why doesn't array accessing of string throw any exception and crashes, whereas `.at` works fine?

IDE: VS2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the [] operator does not check anything whereas at() does. CppReference says :

std::basic_string::at

> Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. Bounds checking is performed, exception of type std::out_of_range will be thrown on invalid access.

std::basic_string::operator[]

> Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::string::at` and `std::string::operator[]` work different.

- The `at(size_t)` method checks the current size of the string: if it is going out of bounds - it will throw an exception.
- The `operator[](size_t)` is a direct access to the chunk of memory. So the problem would be during runtime.

[std::string::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/)

[std::string::at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/)

Answer (score 1):

With a string `s` of length *n* you can access the items at indices 0 through *n*-1, inclusive, with both `[]` and `at`, with well-defined behavior.

Accessing the item at index *n* via `[]` is <sup>(1)</sup>guaranteed to yield a reference to a zero object, while accessing it via `at` is <sup>(2)</sup>guaranteed to throw an `out_of_range` exception.

The former behavior is for compatibility with expectations for C programming, while the latter behavior is for ensured correctness.

Indeed, the `at` method is guaranteed to throw an `out_of_range` exception for any index outside the range 0 through *n*-1.

With `[]` the index you access is <sup>(3)</sup>*required* to be in the range 0 through *n*. And that means that using an index outside of that range, is Undefined Behavior.

---

<sup><sup>1)</sup> C++14 21.4.5/2 about `basic_string::operator[]`: “*Returns*: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type
`charT` with value `charT()`, where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior”.

<sup>2)</sup>. C++14 21.4.6/5 about `basic_string::at`: “*Throws*: `out_of_range` if `pos >= size()`”, where the indexing type is unsigned.

<sup>3)</sup> C++14 21.4.5/1 about `basic_string::operator[]`: “*Requires*: `pos <= size`.”</sup>